# Linear approximation (surface area question)

Tags: calculus

[image]

The surface area of a sphere of radius $r$ is given by $A=4{\pi}r^2$. Use the linear approximation or differentials to compute the approximate percent change in the surface area if the radius of the sphere decreases by $3$%

I attached my solution.

Comment: You have been asked percentage change, Hence compute $\frac{dA}{A}$

Comment: I just put dA instead of dA/A. The answer will be 24%?

Comment: Please see the solution the second one is what you have been asked to solve and you will understand why it is called linear approximation when compared to the exact result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = 4\pi r^2$

r decrease by 3%, Hence the new r = 0.97r

The new area $A_1 = 4\pi )(.97r)^2 = 4\pi (0.9409) r^2$

Change in area $ = (0.9409-1) (4\pi r^2)$

Percentage change$ = \frac{-0.0591 (4\pi r^2)}{4\pi r^2} = -5.91$%

This is the right answer.

You can also use what you have mentioned which is $\frac{dA}{A} = \frac{8\pi rdr}{4\pi r^2} = \frac{2dr}{r}$

But you know $\frac{dr}{r} = -0.03$  Hence percentage change $= 2\times (-0.03)=-0.06 = -6$% $ \approx -0.0591 = -5.91$%
Thanks

Satish